# Professor asked to write this program in python:

Tags: python, loops, nested

Professor asked to write this program in python:

Problem
Write a program to prompt for the number of triangles and the height of each triangle, then print out all the specified triangles.

The triangles should have the following format:

```
How many triangles: 2

The height of the triangle: 3

1  3     5  
 7     9   
 11   

The height of the triangle: 4

1     3     5     7   
9    11    13   
15    17   
 19   

Process finished with exit code 0


How many triangles: 3

The height of the triangle: 1

1   

The height of the triangle: 3

1     3     5   
  7     9   
 11   

The height of the triangle: 5

 1     3     5     7     9   
 11    13    15    17   
 19    21    23   
 25    27   
 29   

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I got this so far:

```
number = eval(input("Enter height"))

for i in range(1, number+1):
    for j in range(i, 10):
        print(j+i, end="\t")
    print("\n")
    print()
```

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: What are you stuck on?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum or a code writing service. Please take the time to read [ask] and the links it contains.  You should spend some time working your way through [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), practicing the examples. It will give you an introduction to the tools Python has to offer and you may even start to get ideas for solving your problem.

Comment: I am stuck on following the number sequence to the next line 
1     3     5     7     9   
11    13    15    17   19    21    23   
 25    27   
 29

Answer (score 0):

you need to take the range in opposite order :

```
number = int(input(("Height of triangle : ")))
odd_number = 1
for i in range(number, 0, -1):
    for j in range(0, i):
        print("{}".format(odd_number), end="\t")
        odd_number += 2
    print("\n")
```